# vhdl "expression is not constant"

Tags: vhdl

I do have following vhdl code which gives an error "expression is not constant" for the line *"signal FiltReg"*:

```
--FILE A--
PORT
(
FindParam   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(48 DOWNTO 0);
...
);

ARCHITECTURE a OF b IS
SIGNAL MAtaps : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
FindParam <= (MAtaps & ...);

PROCESS (clk, clr_n)
  BEGIN
  IF clr_n = '0' THEN
    MAtaps <= (OTHERS => '0');
  ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
    MAtaps <= param2((MAtaps'HIGH) DOWNTO 0); 
  END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

.

```
 --FILE B--
 PORT
 (
 FindParam   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(48 DOWNTO 0);
 ...
 );

 -- Local signals
   signal MAtaps     : integer range 0 to 16;
   signal FiltReg    : UNSIGNED(MAtaps DOWNTO 0); 


BEGIN

    MAtaps <= to_integer(unsigned(FindParam(48 DOWNTO 44)));
```

It looks like the signal declaration has to be constant which is not the case.

**Question:** Is there a solution or workaround in order to use MAtaps for the signal FiltReg declaration?

**EDIT:**
The Quartus error message is:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a VHDL language problem, it appears to be a synthesis restriction (e.g. Quartus Error 10779). The declaration of FiltReg is valid VHDL. However the value of MAtaps is derived from the default value in it's declaration (0, the leftmost value of it's range, at the time the FiltReg declaration is elaborated). FiltReg would have a range of 0 downto 0, a length of one.  If you'd like someone to propose a work around, provide a [mcve] including complete error messages. Otherwise MAtaps could be class constant instead of signal.

Comment: The reason the declaration of FiltReg is valid VHDL can be found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations NOTE 2 ("Signals are given initial values by initializing their drivers."), 14.7.3.4 Signal update, 14.7.2 Drivers, 14.4 Elaboration of a declarative part/14.4.2.5 Object declarations ("d) Any initial value is assigned to the object.").

Comment: I added the Quartus error message

Answer (score 0):

No. `MAtaps` needs to be *static*, that is, fixed at compile time. (VHDL is a *hardware* description language. You can't have a variable amount of hardware.) `MAtaps` can be a constant or a generic, but it can't be another signal or a variable.